# Reading and answering a text question from a image?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, computation-models, image-processing

I wanted to see what models would be best suited for providing a image (see the link below) and having the model perform a image to text (OCR of some kind) and laying out the contents of the image in a "question" "answers" format.

This gets more tricky as I would like to include pictures between the question and answer at a later date as well so I would need a way for the model to section out the question part from the answer part and understand that there might be a image that is part of the question as well.

Any models that would make a good start here for research's (has this already been done?) or if no models are good for the task then what is the best approach for training a model to complete these tasks.

https://i.imgur.com/ffCo7PJ.png